# How to create your own methods like model.association.build in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there is some standard way to create methods like the build method, which is generated on a has_many association. For illustration, assuming the following setup

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :post
end
```

Rails automatically generates a post.comments.build method. Is there a standard way or The Rails Way to create my own method like this? I tried it by defining the method on the singleton class of the comments object, like so:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_initialize do
  class << comments
   def go
    #do something where I can access the the 'owning' post object
   end
  end
 end
end
```

But this code seemed to break after an ActiveRecord update. So, I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: So you want to define method on `has_many` association, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add methods to the association by passing a block to the `has_many` method call and defining the method. An example taken from [`the docs`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

```
has_many :employees do
  def find_or_create_by_name(name)
    first_name, last_name = name.split(" ", 2)
    find_or_create_by(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
  end
end
```